# NumberSpinner constraints not working in DataGrid

Tags: dojo

I am using inline editing of enhancedgrid cells and have a NumberSpinner element. The constraints of this numberspinner don't work when editing inline. The required property works fine though.
My code:

```
{field: 'msorder', width: '10%', name: 'Milestone Order',editable: true, type: dojox.grid.cells._Widget, widgetClass: dijit.form.NumberSpinner, widgetProps: {required:true,smallDelta:1, editorParams:{constraints:{ min:-1000, max:1000, places:0 }} }}
```

I have also tried:

```
{field: 'msorder', width: '10%', name: 'Milestone Order',editable: true, type: dojox.grid.cells._Widget, widgetClass: dijit.form.NumberSpinner, widgetProps: {required:true,smallDelta:1, constraints:{ min:-1000, max:1000, places:0 } }}
```

Comment: in what context are you using that field declaration? have a jsfiddle perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what version of `Dojo` you use, but there is known bug in 1.6 that constraints are ignored in grid widgets. However, I solve that problem doing a little overwriting standard `NumberSpinner`.

```
dojo.require("dijit.form.NumberSpinner");

dojo.addOnLoad(function() {

    dojo.declare("mySpinner", [ dijit.form.NumberSpinner], {

            validator: function(v, c){

                var MIN= -1000;
                var MAX = 1000;

                c.min= MIN;
                c.max = MAX ;
                return ((v < MAX ) && (v > MIN));   
            },

    });

    var dateBox = new mySpinner({}).placeAt('foo');
    dateBox.set("value", 1000);

});
```

(Now, in your grid structure you should use `mySpinner` of course, and it should do the trick).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tvUaK/135/

Comment: You are definitely a problem solving factory. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3):

There is an easier solution, guys:

**constraint:{min:0,max:24}**

`{field: "hours", name: "Stunden",type: dojox.grid.cells._Widget, widgetClass: dijit.form.NumberSpinner, constraint:{min:0,max:24},  widgetProps: {smallDelta:0.25, intermediateChanges:true,}},`

It has to be outside of widgetProps and in singular...

Answer (score 0):

I used another way to solve that problem. I define the type of cell as *Widget* and then I create the widget on get method.

```
{
 field: 'msorder',
 width: '10%',
 name: 'Milestone Order',
 editable: true,
 type: dojox.grid.cells._Widget,
 get: function(rowIndex, item) {
   var store = this.grid.store,
       value = store.getValue(item, 'value');

   this.widget = new dijit.form.NumberSpinner({ value:0,
     constraints:{ min:-1000, max:1000 }
   });

   return value;
 }
}
```

With this implementation I was able to set different constraints for each cell on the grid.